# What I found [was/were] a few gears

Tags: grammar, conjugations

In "*What I found [was/were] a few gears*", which is correct?

I think "were" is, since the "principle of proximity" must be applying here, in my view.

> Dad sends me to the garage to find some details for his broken alarm. I come back and say, "What I was able to find [were/was] some gears only."

Answer (score 1):

In formal writing or in a prepared speech, "were" would be expected. In any other context, "was" is fine.

From a *prescriptivist* standpoint --which only comes into play in formal contexts like standardized tests-- the pronoun "what" represents "some gears", which is plural, therefore "were" is the only correct answer.

But from a *descriptivist* standpoint --which applies to everything else-- even highly educated native speakers in that context could say "were" or "was".

Answer (score 0):

As a native english speaker, I would say "was a". I'm not sure what the technical reason is for why. Maybe it's because of the "a" (singular). "were a" feels wrong to me (again, I'm not sure what the technical reason is for why).

A bit of commentary:

Instead of "*What I found was a few gears*", I would personally say "I only found a few gears". "*What I found was a few gears*" sounds more like an internal-thought narration that one might read in a book.

Instead of "*What I was able to find was some gears only.*", I would personally just say "I was only able to find some gears". For some reason that sounds more casual/comfortable/natural to myself.